# python - returns incorrect positive #

Tags: python, math, module, quadratic, function

what i'm trying to do is write a quadratic equation solver but when the solution should be `-1`, as in `quadratic(2, 4, 2)` it returns `1`

what am i doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math
def quadratic(a, b, c):
        #a = raw_input("What\'s your `a` value?\t")
        #b = raw_input("What\'s your `b` value?\t")
        #c = raw_input("What\'s your `c` value?\t")
        a, b, c = float(a), float(b), float(c)
        disc = (b*b)-(4*a*c)
        print "Discriminant is:\n" + str(disc)
        if disc >= 0:
                root = math.sqrt(disc)
                top1 = b + root
                top2 = b - root
                sol1 = top1/(2*a)
                sol2 = top2/(2*a)
                if sol1 != sol2:
                        print "Solution 1:\n" + str(sol1) + "\nSolution 2:\n" + str(sol2)
                if sol1 == sol2:
                        print "One solution:\n" + str(sol1)
        else:
                print "No solution!"
```

EDIT: it returns the following...

```
>>> import mathmodules
>>> mathmodules.quadratic(2, 4, 2)
Discriminant is:
0.0
One solution:
1.0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless the formula has changed since I went to school (one can never be too sure), it's `(-b +- sqrt(b^2-4ac)) / 2a`, you have `b` in your code.

[edit] May I suggest a refactor?

```
def quadratic(a, b, c):
    discriminant = b**2 - 4*a*c
    if discriminant < 0:
      return []
    elif discriminant == 0:
      return [-b / (2*a)]
    else:
      root = math.sqrt(discriminant)
      return [(-b + root) / (2*a), (-b - root) / (2*a)]

print quadratic(2, 3, 2) # []
print quadratic(2, 4, 2) # [-1]                    
print quadratic(2, 5, 2) # [-0.5, -2.0]
```

Comment: You can also get complex answers if you change line 3 to: return [complex(-b, math.sqrt(-discriminant))/(2*a), \
complex(-b, -math.sqrt(-discriminant))/(2*a)]

Comment: +1 - Nice work, tokland, but it would have been possible to return the complex conjugate roots for the negative discriminate case, since Python supports complex numbers so nicely.  And the discriminant equal to zero case has two roots - one of them is zero.  I would recommend those two changes

Comment: @bvmou, @duffymo. Indeed, but I was trying to mimic the original code, which does not contemplate complex numbers. But yes, you can add them as you describe. @duffymo: I don't get that discriminant=0 implies that 0 is a root, but two equal roots (-b/2a). I was going to do it (don't bother to check disc=0), but again, the original code considered it as a single solution.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the quadratic is

```
x = (-b +/- sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/2a
```

but what you have coded up is

```
x = (b +/- sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/2a
```

So that's why you get the sign error.

Answer (score 1):

The signs of `top1` and `top2` are wrong, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Answer (score 0):

```
top1 = b + root
top2 = b - root
```

Should be:

```
top1 = -b + root
top2 = -b - root
```